# Why isn't the context properties of a canvas not changing according to button clicks?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I am creating an extension that allows users to draw on top of webpages. They have three options so far, to draw with a pen, highlighter, or to erase what they already drew.

The problem I am running into developing this is that I cannot seem to switch between each drawing utensil. I have two files working together; a popup.js and a utensils.js

popup.js:

```
var eventDelegator = document.getElementById("eventDelegate");

eventDelegator.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "createCanvas.js"});

  if(target.id == "penButton" || target.id == "penPic" || target.id == "penName"){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {button: 'pen'});
    }
    );
  }
  if(target.id == "highlightButton" || target.id == "highlighterName" || target.id == "highlighterPic"){
    //alert("highlighter");
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {button: 'highlighter'});
    }
  );
  }
  /*else if(target.id == "eraserButton"){
    //chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "Utensils/Eraser.js"});
  }*/
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "Test Files/utensils.js"});

});
```

utensils.js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("webpageCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var position = {x: 0, y: 0};
var last = {lastX: 0, lastY: 0};

function main(utensilClicked){
  if(utensilClicked == 'pen'){
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.lineJoin = 'round';
    context.lineCap = 'round';
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  }
  if(utensilClicked == 'highlighter'){
    context.lineWidth = 20;
    context.lineJoin = 'miter';
    context.lineCap = 'square';
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(13, 213, 252, .4)";
  }

  function draw(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(last.lastX, last.lastY);
    context.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    last.lastX = position.x;
    last.lastY = position.y;

    position.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    position.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  }, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    //context.beginPath();
    //context.moveTo(position.x, position.y);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    //When the mouse button isn't being held, then it removes the event listener
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
  }, false);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender){
  main(request.button);
});
```

When one button is clicked in one instance, then the drawing feature works out fine. But when another button is clicked OR the same one is clicked, the drawing feature ceases. If I click the buttons a number of times, my mouse cursor becomes the "no symbol" if I click and drag.

I suspect that utensils.js is being injected over and over with a button click but I do not know if that is correct.

Bump #1

Comment: From above code and description, every time you click the button, you will call `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "createCanvas.js"});`, looks like a new `canvas` will be created? Please show your entire code and make sure all the manipulation is on the same canvas.

Comment: @HaibaraAi, the createCanvas.js script has an if statement checking if the canvas already exists. If it already exists, then nothing happens. Do you still need the code?